# PayPal Instant Update for Express Checkout stopped working [sandbox]

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I spent like four weeks coding a plugin to work with PayPal Express Checkout instant update. It was working perfectly in the end with shipping and taxes updating as expected.

However, two days ago, the checkout layout got changed automatically from the classic one to the mobile-responsive version. Previously when I had the callback for instant update defined it automatically used to switch from the mobile-friendly version to the classic version. Now that is no longer the case and the instant update features don't seem to work at all with the mobile-friendly checkout.

Is there anything I can do about it or has PayPal stopped supporting instant update just when I finished my plugin?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem..

UPDATE..

After emailing PayPal tech support they finally replied..

> **Unsupported features**
>
> In-Context Express Checkout does not support:
>
> - Parallel payments or multi-seller payments
> - Callback / Instant Update API operations
> - Billing agreements that use the deprecated    SetCustomerBillingAgreement API operation
> - Seamless checkout for a Log in with PayPal integration

So yes, they stopped supporting instant update with Express Checkout, though they haven't removed the [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECInstantUpdateAPI/) as of yet.